# Using Ajax in Yii.?

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I am working on job portal,and have a search module for employers to search for application.I want to use ajax to list the application after search, listing the results in the same page.How should I do it.?,Below is the screenshot of the module.Have tried the following things.[image]

//Contoller Code//

```
public function actionSearch()
{
               $model = new SearchEmployee();
               /*Getting Data From Search Form For Processing */

          if (isset($_POST['SearchEmployee'])) {

                $model->attributes = $_POST['SearchEmployee'];

                $category   =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['category'];
                $skills     =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['skills'];
                $experience =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['experience'];

             $ajaxmodel = SearchEmployee::model()->find(array(
            'select' => array('*'), "condition" => "category_id=$category AND key_skills like'%$skills%'AND experience=$experience",

             ));

             if($model==null)
             {
                  Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "No Results");
                  $this->renderPartial('search');
             }
             else
             {
                  $this->renderPartial('search', array('model' => $ajaxmodel));
                  Yii::app()->end();
             }
```

}

// In views,Not posting full codes just codes to show the ajax results,//

```
   <div class="view">

       <h1>Results </h1>

     <div class="view" id="id">

       <h1> Records Display </h1>

       <h4>Name: <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'skills Required'); ?></h4>
       <h4>Skills: <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Skills Required'); ?></h4>
       <h4>Experience: <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Skills Required'); ?></h4>
       <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('VIew Details'); ?></h5>
       </div>

       </div>
```

Is this way to do...

Answer (score 0):

In your view just enable ajax, for example:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'client-document-form',
        'method' => 'post',
        'action' => $url,
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        'errorMessageCssClass' => 'required_field_text'
    )); ?>
```

This line `enableAjaxValidation => true` need be true also in your actions add this line `$this->performAjaxValidation($model);`

**UPDATE:**

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'update-profile-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            'errorMessageCssClass' => 'required_field_text',
            'clientOptions' => array(
                'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                'validateOnChange' => false,
                'hideErrorMessage' => true,
                'beforeValidate' => 'js:function(form) {
                    return validate.beforeValidate("update-profile-form");
                }',
                'afterValidate' => 'js:function(form, data, hasError) {
                    validate.afterValidate(data, "update-profile-form");
                }'
            ),
```

Comment: Arthur...how can get the result from contoller to view page...can u give me a brief explanation.